# File not found Apache error when navigating in Laravel 9 routes

Tags: laravel, apache, laravel-9

I've installed Laravel 9.0.2 on an Apache machine under PHP 8.1.2, and I have a problem. When I browse the site and ask for any route, whether it exists or not, sometimes I get the expected content (Laravel 404 error if the route does not exist), but sometimes I get a blank page telling me.

> ["File not found"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkDMV.png).

I think it's an Apache error, but I don't understand why it appears.

Comment: There's not enough information to go by here. Is there a pattern to the apache errors? e.g. does it happen to all files under a specific path (like e.g. all routes under `/a/*` work file but all routes under `/b/*` show this message). Does the corresponding directory you are trying to access exist under `public` e.g. if `/b/*` don't work do you have a directory called `public/b` ?

Comment: The error appears for any route whether it exists or not. The base file is set to public and I even tried to access an image located at "app/public/images/1/files/2022-02-14/1-1-azerty.png" and it sometimes shows me a Laravel 404 and sometimes a "File not found."

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

It seems that was been the Apache who haven't totally taken in consideration the new config. There was multiples process after the Apache reboot and the oldest one conflicted with the latest.
Try to kill the old process or reboot the server to fix this.